# Why UIAlertView need to be localized?

Tags: iphone

I have declared UIAlertView *alert in the .h file. alloc alert in func1.  and show & release in func2.  This would cause memory BAD_EXEC_ACCESS issue.

```
-(void) func1 
{
alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"To Confirm." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

}

-(void) func2
{
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

If I do following it's OK.  If everything  localized in a function then its OK. Why?

```
-(void) func1
{
alert= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"To Confirm." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the 2 function approach, you are not retaining alert in func1, and this memory is leaking. Then when you access alert (to show it) in func2, it's retain count is still zero and could already have been deallocated.
If you add

```
 [alert retain];
```

in func1 of the double-function case, it should work.

In the case of a single function, you are allocating and using and releasing all within the same scope, so there are no memory issues.

You could also declare a

```
 @property (nonatomic,retain) UIAlertView *alert;
```

in your .h file, and then reference it as self.alert in the functions.
Be sure to @synthesize it and also to release it in the dealloc method.

Comment: `alloc` carries an implicit `retain` with it. I don't think that's the actual problem—my guess would be that `func2` is getting called more than once, and thus over-releasing the alert.

Comment: I think Noah is right. I'm wondering what func1 and 2 are- does the whole controller go out of scope between 1 and 2?

Comment: Did the issue get resolved? How are you using these functions? Could you post the code?

Answer (score -1):

Your alertView loses scope when you alloc it inside one method and then try to access it from another one.

Either call a [alertView retain] after you allocate it in func1 (and release it once you're done), or alloc it in func2

Comment: Mike's answer says the same thing but is better formatted so refer to that one :D

Comment: The OP says that `alert` is declared in the header file, so scope shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: And if you're thinking of methods like ViewDidLoad, anything you allocate there remains during the view's lifecycle. Allocating something in your own methods is where the object loses scope.

Comment: `alert` is an iVar declared in the header file. Calling func2 before func1 or calling func2 twice may be causing crashes, but it is certainly not a issue with variable scope. If `alert` was improperly declared, the class wouldn't compile.

Comment: I tried out the code and seems like you are correct.... I retract my earlier statement :) you learn something everyday!

Comment: So now that we're all bruised and bloody and smarter, what is the answer to the OP's question?

Comment: BTW, the correct answer was given by Noah Witherspoon in his comment on Mike's answer.

Comment: Well, I agree with Noah that theoretically the alloc has a retain, but we still don't know what is causing the problem here.

Comment: Yes, we do. If the only calls are [controller func1]; [controller func2]; no crash happens. Unbalanced calls will crash, or cause memory leaks. The talk about scope is wrong and doesn't apply here. The extra retain is useless too. (Why take ownership twice?!)

Comment: @Johan... yes, I am aware, as I admitted previously. That was a joke.